# How can I launch Grub-Customizer?

Tags: unity, grub2, 13.10

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10. I've installed grub-customizer and re-checked my installations of unity and grub-customizer. When I try and reinstall grub-customizer I get the message that "grub-customizer is already the newest version" But, when I click on unity and type"grub" all I can see is the file folder where grub is. In fact I can't find ANY apps with unity. I guess I have to repair unity? I tried to reinstall it but got the same message about "unity-scope-home already being the newest version." How do I repair whatever is broken so I can launch grub?? Thanks

Comment: If memory doesn't fails me, you can't use the Grub Customizer in recent version of GRUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unity searchs apps from .desktop file created by the app during installation. Some time the app doesn't create such file. 
just logout and log back in.. See if now you can find the app. Or you can launch from command prompt. Type `grub` and keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the command

Comment: Thank you. Running grub from a terminal prompt did it and I was able to get my delay-to-boot and boot order to my liking. I am now seeking info about editing the .desktop file so I can put apps there (or remove them). Not even the LibreOffice software shows up when I search unity. In fact, I can't find a .desktop dir or file and when I search for .desktop using unity I just get examples.desktop. Thanks again.